# A general theory of multiplicity-free actions of $G\times H$?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

There seem to be a bunch of different results of the form "This nice
representation $V$ of $G\times H$ breaks up as $\bigoplus_\lambda V_\lambda
\otimes W_\lambda$, where the $(V_\lambda)$ are distinct irreps of $G$ 
and the $(W_\lambda)$ are distinct irreps of $H$."

Examples I know (described algebraically):

1. $G = S_n$, $H = GL(k)$, $V = ({\mathbb C}^k)^{\otimes n}$.
2. $G = H$, $V = Fun(G)$ (the Peter-Weyl theorem)
3. $G = GL(m)$, $H = GL(n)$, $V = Sym({\mathbb C}^m \otimes {\mathbb C}^n)$.

I know there should be some analogous one with $O(m)$ and $Sp(n)$...

My questions:

1. What are other examples?
2. Is there a general theory of these, that in particular would
   encompass Peter-Weyl? (So not just about actions on symmetric algebras.)

Comment: I expect they won't be general enough to satisfy 2, but my recollection from 7 years ago was that Howe's lectures on multiplicity free actions were excellent (MR1321638).

Comment: I should note that 2 implies the $m=n$ case of 3.

Answer (score 2):

When $K$ is a complex reductive linear algebraic group, an affine variety $X$ equipped with an action of $K$ is called **multiplicity-free** if its ring of functions $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is multiplicity-free as a $K$-module. When $K$ is connected, this means that a Borel subgroup has a dense orbit on $X$ (if $X$ is also normal, such a variety is called **spherical**).

In the question's example (2), $K = G \times G$ and $X = G$ (with $G \times G$ acting by left and right multiplication) and $V= \mathbb{C}[G]$. In example (3), $K=GL(m)\times GL(n)$ and $X = (\mathbb{C}^m \otimes \mathbb{C}^n)^*$.

There is a general theory of spherical varieties, and there are classifications. For example,
Kac[MR575790], Leahy[MR1650378] and Benson-Ratcliff[MR1382030] did the case where $X$ is itself a representation of $K$ (see also [Howe and Umeda, MR1116239] and [Knop, MR1653036]). Homogeneous spherical varieties were classified in [Kramer, MR0528837] and [Brion, MR0822838].

**Edit:** As pointed out by Allen in the comments, the condition that $V$ be multiplicity-free as a $(G \times H)$-module is weaker than the condition on $V$ in the original question. Let's call a $V$ as in the question **strongly MF**. As Allen points out in another comment, $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is strongly MF if and only if $B_G \times U_H$ and $U_G \times B_H$ have open orbits on $X$ (here $B_G$ is a Borel subgroup of $G$, and $U_G$ a maximal unipotent subgroup of $G$).

Comment: Okay, but saying $X$ is a spherical $G\times H$-variety only says that each $V_\lambda \otimes W_\mu$ shows up at most once; it would allow e.g. $V_\lambda \otimes (W_\mu \oplus W_\nu)$. Do you see a geometric way to enforce the stronger multiplicity-free statement I'm asking for above?

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Didn't read your question carefully enough. 

Comment: Let $G$ and $H$ be connected reductive and $X$ an affine $G\times H$-variety. Let $U \subset G$ and $N \subset H$ be maximal unipotent subgroups. Then $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is multiplicity-free in your stronger sense if and only if $X//U$ is a multiplicity-free $H$-variety and $X//N$ is a multiplicity-free $G$-variety. Another way to restate your condition is that $X$ is multiplicity-free and that the two projections of its weight monoid (moment cone) to the character groups of the maximal tori of $G$ and $H$ are injective. Can this be made nicer and more geometric?

Comment: I guess you're saying that the usual condition is that $B_G \times B_H$ have an open orbit, but the stronger one is that $U_G \times B_H$ and $B_G \times U_H$ should have open orbits?

Comment: $X$ is indeed multiplicity-free iff $B_G \times B_H$ has an open orbit. I hadn't thought of phrasing the stronger condition as nicely as you just did, but I agree that it is equivalent to the strong multiplicity-freeness of the $G\times H$-module $\mathbb{C}[X]$. (The proof for the spherical case generalizes).

Answer (score 1):

Well, one "general" theorem is

> If A and B are semi-simple algebras acting faithfully on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ such that $\mathrm{End}_A(V)=B$ and *vice versa*, then tensoring with $V$ is a Morita equivalence between $A$-modules and $B$-modules.

You mostly have infinite examples up there, but they are direct limits of situations like this.  Presumably with a little more care, one could make this work for something "graded finite dimensional" or a Hilbert space.

If you think for a moment about what it means to be a Morita equivalence between semi-simple algebras, it means must have exactly this multiplicity free form.  Of course, the question of how to find situations like this is a little more fraught.